# Assert in Selenium C#

Tags: selenium

Is there a *Assert* class present in Selenium C# just like we have in Coded UI test.

Or I should use the *Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert* class to perform asserts in Selenium?

Comment: What is *"Coded UI test"*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you would use the `Assert` class in your unit test framework, in your case [MSTest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework).

The Selenium library doesn't have responsibility over test framework type of functions, including `asserts`.

You can use `FluentAssertions` which supports many different frameworks including MSTest which might minimize changes needed if you need to switch frameworks for any reason.

Answer (score 3):

The `Assert` class is available with either the [MSTest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Unit_Testing_Framework) or [NUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NUnit) framework.

I used NUnit, and there is the `Assert` class as in below line of code.

**Sample code**:

```
Assert.AreEqual(AmericaEmail, "SupportUsa@Mail.com", "Strings are not matching");
```

Answer (score 2):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182532.aspx

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.Url = "Your URL";
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        //Your first test method
        var element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ID"));
        Assert.IsTrue(element.Displayed);
        Assert.AreEqual(element.Text.ToLower(), "Expected text".ToLower());
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
        //Your second test method
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MSTest or I would rather prefer to write simple assertion method. In Selenium, most of the use cases would be a Boolean check, IsTrue | IsFalse (you can even extend to write more complex assertions), so when you define your own assertion you will get more control of your script, like,

- Taking a screenshot if the assertion fails
- You can live with the failure and continue the test
- You can mark the script as partially passing
- Extract more information from the UI, like JavaScript errors or server errors

Answer (score 0):

To use Assert you have to first create the unit testing project in Visual Studio.

Or import the following reference to the project.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
// Using this you can use the Assert class.

Assert.IsTrue(bool);
Assert.IsFalse(bool);
Assert.AreEqual(string,string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert.Equals(obj1, obj2); // Object comparison
Assert.AreEqual(HomeUrl, driver.Url); // Overloaded, comparison. Same object value
Assert.AreNotEqual(HomeUrl, driver.Url);
Assert.AreSame("https://www.google.com", URL); // For the same object reference

Assert.IsTrue(driver.WindowHandles.Count.Equals(2));
Assert.IsFalse(driver.WindowHandles.Count.Equals(2));

Assert.IsNull(URL); Assert.IsNotNull(URL);
```

Comment: Where are those from (e.g., which framework)?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium C# is not offering an assert class. You have to borrow it from somewhere or write your own implementation.

Writing your own implementation will give you more freedom to manage assertions, as [Peter said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674491/assert-in-selenium-c-sharp/46046538#46046538).

Here is the basic idea. Just create a static class having assert methods like this:

```
public static class MyAssertClass
{
    public static void MyAreEqualMethod(string string1, string string2)
    {
        if (string1 != string2)
        {
          // Throw an exception
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MSTest Framework : Assert Class

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert?view=mstest-net-1.3.2

Answer (score -1):

This way assert can be used for switching into popup's displayed:

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
String alertcontent = alert.Text;
Assert.AreEqual(alertcontent, "Do you want to save this article as draft?");
obj.waitfn(5000);
alert.Accept();
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"switching into popup's displayed"*? Can you elaborate?