# How can I pass or fail a test according the assert method result webdriver C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to pass or fail a test according the assert method result. If one element (in case a dropdown) is displayed in a modal, the tests have to fail automatically.

Another scenario is if the element is not displayed, but it should appear.

What would be some sample code to solve this problem?

I'm looking for some answers here and don't find if it is possible to pass or fail a test depending the result of the assertion method, the result have to be displayed in the Test Explorer menu. I'm using NUnit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assert in Selenium C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674491/assert-in-selenium-c-sharp)

Comment: Jonathan, I didn't find the answer that I looking for in this post. I want to pass (✓) or fail (x) a test, depending the result of assertion thats look for some element in page

Answer (score 0):

NUnit Framework has its own `Asserts`.

```
Assert.AreEqual("Expected Title", driver.GetTitle());
```

See documentation: [Git](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assertions)

Comment: Can I pass ou fail test depending the result of assertion method? Can you provide some sample code please?

Comment: Give me some real life scenario, because I dont get what you want exactly

Comment: When you run your tests, depending on `asserts` it will display checkmark or fail mark on Test Runner or if you are running with `console` it will generate `xml` with fail status for your report

Comment: Im running with Test Runner, and want to do a test sequence of assertions, and depending of the result the checkmark shows if id pass or fail


`var ddSomething = _driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select#formSomethingId"));

            try
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(ddSomething.Displayed);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            return true;`

Comment: why cant you just wrap your code to `try` block and assert true by the end of the try block and catch exception and assert false there?

Comment: Can you elaborate in your answer that it is not Selenium's responsibility to do the checking/asserts (only to communicate/control the browser, etc.)?