# Is there any exception a test can throw to end the test immediately/tell TestNG "stop running this test" and report success instead of ignored?

Tags: selenium, exception, testng

Trying to figure out is there any condition/exception/assumption through which I can end the test execution immediately and report "success" instead of "ignored".

Comment: Try using an [Assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42674491/assert-in-selenium-c-sharp).

Answer (score 0):

When an exception is thrown - if you catch that exception - then that case will be shown as success instead of fail. - so try to catch that exception.

But you cannot end the case execution immediately. In that case - just run only the cases for which you want to test the script and skip all the remaining cases

Comment: But in that case all those skipped tests will be reported as "Ignored" not "passed". I want testNg to check the condition and report "success" without running it because we dont want certain tests to run in prod for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Its good group you tests means tests to be run in production, Regression etc...

```
<test name="Tests"
    parallel="methods" thread-count="2">

    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="production"></include>
        </run>
    </groups>

    <classes>

        <class
            name="my.test.classes" />

    </classes>

</test>
```

In scripting

```
@Test(groups = { "production" })
```